# Slow loading of my Firefox extensions - for all ChromeWindow

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a created by myself Firefox Add-ons and they slowly turn on but the problem is generic.

Check how slow loading:
https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/best-theme-like-google-materia/

`for` loop for each of `browserWindows` array:

```
var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");
var windows = require("sdk/windows");

var browserWindows = windows.browserWindows;
for (let browserWindow of browserWindows) {
    let chromeWindow = viewFor(browserWindow);
    module.enable(chromeWindow);
}
```

And then for the newly opened window:

```
browserWindows.on('open', function(browserWindow) {
    var chromeWindow = viewFor(browserWindow);
    module.enable(chromeWindow);
});
```

And disable for each browser window - `for` loop on the same array:

```
var browserWindows = windows.browserWindows;
for (let browserWindow of browserWindows) {
    let chromeWindow = viewFor(browserWindow);
    module.disable(chromeWindow);
}
```

It seems to me that in these functions loaders for windows is a problem.
Because he does the addition of such a thing that should not slime when turning, eg .:

```
var style = require("sdk/stylesheet/utils");
var self = require("sdk/self");
function enable (window) {
    style.loadSheet(window, self.data.url("toolbars/tabs.css"), "author");
    style.loadSheet(window, self.data.url("toolbars/navigator.css"), "author");
    style.loadSheet(window, self.data.url("toolbars/other-toolbars.css"), "author");
}

 function disable (window) {
    style.removeSheet(window, self.data.url("toolbars/tabs.css"), "author");
    style.removeSheet(window, self.data.url("toolbars/navigator.css"), "author");
    style.removeSheet(window, self.data.url("toolbars/other-toolbars.css"), "author");
}
```

How to do it more efficiently, not to the charge made muddy?

Comment: Maybe inject a script rather then maniuplate the window. And that script on load talks to your main index.js via messaging. I know I had problems with copying an array buffer from my bootstrap.js to windows. Its because their script scopes are different. So I now transfer via postMessage. It works real nicely.